# How to attach a prefab to a GameObject programmatically?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity. Trying to load/attach an .obj file (downloaded and saved in my file system) to a game object in Unity. I've tried using the following code but I have got an error.

```
Resources.Load(My_File_Path).transform.parent = targetGameObject;
```

The error I got:

error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Object' does not contain a definition for`transform' and no extension method `transform' of type`UnityEngine.Object' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have loaded your prefab correctly, but the problem is that you're not handling an instance of the prefab - you're handling the prefab itself, which is an `Object` and not a `GameObject`.

Before you can access GameObject-specific members such as `transform`, you need to [`Instantiate()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) your prefab. This method accepts an argument of type `Object`, so pass in your prefab reference and assign the resultant `GameObject` instance as a child of `targetGameObject`:

```
Object prefabReference = Resources.Load(My_File_Path);
GameObject gameObjectReference = Instantiate(prefabReference) as GameObject;
gameObjectReference.transform.parent = targetGameObject;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I just added ".transform" to your third line and it works without any error. Thanks.

Comment: Also note that in newer versions of Unity, `Instantiate` method is generic and you don't need `as GameObject` part.

Answer (score 1):

creating a game object from a prefab at run-time requires you to instantiate the object.

first, to instantiate a prefab you dont need to worry about the transform just yet....

when using `Resources.Load` -you are going to need to make sure you have a Resources folder in your project. if not make one.

*note that i then make a sub folder in the resources folder called Prefabs. you dont have to though.*

in your resources folder, you can place your prefab item. (drag and drop the finished item from your scene) once you have the prefab its safe to delete if from your scene.

now the code is:

```
GameObject yourobject = Instantiate(Resources.Load("thenameofprefab") )as GameObject;
```

you now have your prefab item in the gameobject yourobject, and can manipulate its transform and rotation freely.

if you make a prefab folder in your resources folder, the method would be

```
GameObject yourobject = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/thenameofprefab") )as GameObject;
```

hope this helps.

p.s. you can set the transform and rotation on that instantiation line, you just need to check the overloads to see how to use it!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you first need to create a prefab from your object. Drag to the scene and then put created GameObject in your assetes.
You can create 
`public GameObject prefab;` in your class.
Then instantiate it like that:
 `GameObject obj =Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero), Quaternion.identity);`
And then you can attach it like you did it before:
`obj.transform.parent = targetGameObject;`

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I wanted to do all this in script instead of dragging and dropping.